# how to get record with a specified character at the specified location in oralce sql

Tags: sql, oracle, select, sql-like

I have a table in oracle DB that has the following data:

```
CHIP_NAME             CHIP_ID
ABC123_0                1
ACB123_A                2
ABC123_AB               3
1ACBDFDFD               4
FDF                     5
...                     ...
```

I am only interested in the rows that has the underscore ('_') as the 6th characters.  So, in the example above, I am only interested in the first 3 rows.

So far, I use the following query:

```
select CHIP_NAME, ID from CHIP_HEADER where CHIP_NAME like '%/_%' escape '/';
```

but this query returns all records that have `_` (underscore) in the CHIP_NAME.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use `substr` to get the sixth character.

```
select * from chip_header where substr(chip_name,6,1) = '_'
```

Comment: yes it would return a null value. so the condition fails and the row wouldn't be returned

Answer (score 2):

You can use (an unescaped) `_` character as a single character wildcard:

```
SELECT chip_name, id
FROM   chip_header
WHERE  chip_name LIKE '_____\_%' ESCAPE '\'
```